# Tracking url status and parameters

Tags: java, firefox, firebug

I send some requests from my site after loading every page to some other different third party sites.
Now i want to track whether one of those request is going well or not to some other third party site and with my required parameters and response status is true or not.

Actually we can see this result in firebug but i want an automation tool for testing this requirement...

Comment: And how it is related to java?

Answer (score 0):

To pick up Honza's answer on the related [Firebug discussion group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/i8wf76M5GqU/discussion), you can see these network requests within Firebug's [Net panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).

For automation you can use the Firebug extension [NetExport](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#NetExport) plus the [Selenium server standalone](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).

You can find a [detailed description](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/) of how to do this in Honza's blog.

Sebastian

Comment: hi Sebastain,
 Using this Honza's blog i can store the net work traffic in a HAR file, ok. but how this HAR file is useful for me to track wether a request from my page with some parameters, to other third party site is going or not? 
How to identify that url with in this file?